# While loop will not break in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

Hey im making a game in C++.  It's college work and the brief states no use of header files and the game must be basic.  The problem is,  after the game ends its still asking for a choice.  Ive tried to break, exit and still no joy.  The program will not exit.
Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my code:
Main

```
int main()          //  The main function is set to int.  
    //  The return value has to be an integer value.
{
    menuText();
    while(menu)     // Loop to revert back to menu when choice is not compatable with options.
    {
        int selection;
        cout<< "Choice: ";
        cin>> selection;

        switch(selection)
        {
        case 1: 
            cout << "Start Game\n";
            playGame();
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Exit Game\n";
            cout << "Please press enter to exit...\n";
            menu = false ;
            break;
        }
    }


    system("pause");    //  To stop the program from exiting prematurely.
    return 0;           //  this is needed because the main is set to return
    //  an integer.
}

int playgame()
status Status = {100,20,80,80,20};// declaration of class members.
    //Contents of PlayGame().............................
    exitGame();
    return 0;
}
void exitGame()
{
    cout << "\n\nPlease press enter to exit the game.";
    return;

}
```

Comment: Do we really need ALL this code to understand the problem? Can you cut the non relevant parts out so it'll be easier to focus on the problem at hand?

Comment: The [homework tag is deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger? Put a breakpoint at your `cout << "Exit Game\n";` line and see what's going on.

Comment: @Lucero Deleted the homework tag.

Comment: @Msonic Ive actually never used the Debugger before.  I wasnt shown how to use it in college and therefore never used it.

Comment: @Pendo826 What IDE are you using? Visual studio? Code blocks? Every IDE has a debugger, you should read about it, you're going to have an easier time debugging your applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding you, but from what I understand - you want the game to end after `playGame()` function was finished (correct me if I am wrong).

To do so, you simply need to set `menu=false;`  in this block as well - or as an alternative - remove the `break;` statement from this case. It will make the flow "fall" to the exit case.

Comment: Do i put it in the Switch or the actual playGame()?

Comment: @Pendo826: In the switch block.

Answer (score 2):

You basically do this:

```
int playGame()
{
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    bool menu = true;
    while(menu){
        cout<< "Choice: ";
        cin>> selection;

        switch(selection)
        {
        case 1: 
            cout << "Start Game\n";
            playGame();
            break; // This break symbolizes that you want to end switch statement
                   // not the whole loop
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You may do something like this:

```
#define GAME_COMPLETED -1 /* Will close the game */
#define GAME_RESERVER 0

if( playGame() == GAME_COMPLETED){
    menu = false;
}

// And of course at the end of the playGame:
return GAME_COMPLETED;
```

<del>And are you sure that you don't want to use `case '1':` instead of `case 1:`?</del>

Comment: selection is an integer so it should be 1 and not '1'.

Comment: @BleepBloop thanks, crossed out :)